# Can VirtualBox prevent Mac OS X Yosemite to boot properly?

Tags: hard-drive, startup, macos, virtualbox

After a few days of good experience with Yosemite, my Macbook pro cannot boot anymore. After 30 or 40% of boot, it just restarts. Here are what I did to fix it:

- Booting to single-user, runnign `fsck -fy`, since the laptop fallen one day or two ago and I was suspicious about hard drive. But `fsck` told everything is fine with my hard drive. I don't think it is checking bad sectors.
- Resetting PRAM
- Booting to Recovery, checking hard disk via Disk Utilities
- Reinstalling Yosemite from OS X Utilities

Now it does not even boot into recovery (reboots after 30%).

My last try was to verbose boot, and the last message printed out before rebooting was:

```
VBoxDrv: Failed to open kernel symbols (rc=-102)
```

In another try, the last message was:

```
VBoxAdpDrv: version (some number)
```

I had VirtualBox installed on my MacBook and worked prior to upgrading to Yosemite (in Mavericks). I did not check it in Yosemite.

So my question is: can VirtualBox prevent Yosemite from boot? Can I uninstall it using single-user boot (which is the only successful boot on my computer now)? Or do you have a better idea to get it fixed?

Comment: Obviously your is doing something it should not.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I was very hopeful to recover it after removing all VirtualBox components in single-user mode. I removed everything including *vbox* from /, now it won't prompt any messages about Vbox in the verbose mode, but reboots again (no particular messages are shown before reboot). Any ideas?

Comment: no other then cmd-r to restore your Yosemite and disconnect any external devices. otherwise run the AHT (apple hardware test)

Comment: @Buscar웃 I am afraid cmd-r is not working anymore. The reboot happens before OS X Utilities are shown :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a serious hardware error (failure of main board) was preventing installation of Yosomite. The reason I saw Virtual Box error was just a matter of chance, it printed out the lost error message before the computer crashed due to the main board error